# Return line number or subsequent text of a text file string search

Tags: vbscript

I have a several text files that have thousands of lines each with this being an example of a typical line:

```
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&REV_09    Realtek\5x64\FORCED\PCIe_5.810.1218.2012\   Netrtle.inf Realtek 1   12/18/2012,5.810.1218.2012  Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
```

The script I'm working on does a string search for that first segment of text:

```
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&REV_09
```

My script narrows down which files have this string, but what I really need is for it then to return the next string on that same line:

```
Realtek\5x64\FORCED\PCIe_5.810.1218.2012\
```

Once I have this string I can continue on with the rest of the script which is just extracting the Realtek folder from a 7zip.

I've seen this has been done with other languages on Stack but I can't find anything for VBS.  I could probably find an answer if I knew how to phrase the task better. I'd really appreciate some advise on grabbing that second string.

For background, this is the script I'm working on.  It looks through all the text files in C:\scripts\ for a string returned by a WMI query for CompatibleID of device drivers with code 28 (no driver installed):

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_PnPEntity " _ 
        & "WHERE ConfigManagerErrorCode = 28") 
For Each objItem in colItems 
 Dim arrCompatibleIDs
 aarCompatibleIDs = objItem.CompatibleID
 for each objComp in aarCompatibleIDs
 Dim FirstID
 FirstID = objComp
Exit For
Next 
Next

strSearchFor = firstID
objStartFolder = "C:\scripts"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    'Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
    strFile = "C:\scripts\" & objFile.Name
    set objFile = objFSO.getFile(strFile)
    if objFile.size > 0 then
        If InStr(objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile).ReadAll, strSearchFor) > 0 Then
            msgbox(objfile.name)
        Else
            WScript.Sleep (100)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search for a fixed needle and a variable thread in a haystack, you can use some InStr()s or a RegExp. To get you started:

```
  Dim sHaystack : sHaystack = Join(Array( _
       "hay hay" _
     , "fixed_needle variable_thread hay" _
     , "hay hay" _
  ), vbCrLf)
  Dim sNeedle : sNeedle = "fixed_needle" & " "
  Dim nPosN   : nPosN   = Instr(sHaystack, sNeedle)
  If 0 < nPosN Then
     nPosN = nPosN + Len(sNeedle)
     Dim nPosT : nPosT = Instr(nPosN, sHaystack, " ")
     If 0 < nPosN Then
        WScript.Echo "Instr()", qq(Mid(sHaystack, nPosN, nPosT - nPosN))
     Else
        WScript.Echo "no thread"
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo "no needle"
  End If
  Dim reNT : Set reNT = New RegExp
  reNT.Pattern = sNeedle & "(\S+) "
  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reNT.Execute(sHayStack)
  If 1 = oMTS.Count Then
     WScript.Echo "RegExp ", qq(oMTS(0).SubMatches(0))
  Else
     WScript.Echo "no match"
  End If
```

output:

```
Instr() "variable_thread"
RegExp  "variable_thread"
```

If you change the haystack to

```
  Dim sHaystack : sHaystack = Join(Array( _
       "hay hay" _
     , "fixed_needle no_variable_thread_hay" _
     , "hay hay" _
  ), vbCrLf)
```

output:

```
Instr() "no_variable_thread_hay
hay"
no match
```

you see that there is more work needed to make the Instr() approach bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input file seems to be tab-separated, you could do something like this:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ConfigManagerErrorCode = 28"
For Each entity In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  For Each cid In entity.CompatibleID
    firstID = cid
    Exit For
  Next
Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each f In objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder).Files
  If f.Size > 0 Then
    For line In Split(f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
      arr = Split(line, vbTab)
      If arr(0) = firstID Then MsgBox arr(1)
    Next
  End If
Next
```

---

On a more general note, you shouldn't do stuff like this:

```
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
  strFile = "C:\scripts\" & objFile.Name
  set objFile = objFSO.getFile(strFile)
  if objFile.size > 0 then
    If InStr(objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile).ReadAll, strSearchFor) > 0 Then
...
```

The [`Files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18b41306) collection already contains [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf) objects, so it's utterly pointless to build a pathname from the object's properties (which BTW include a [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9kfyt6a) property that gives you the full path) only to obtain the exact same object you already have. Plus, file objects have a method [`OpenAsTextStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfw5c59), so you can directly open them as text files without taking a detour like `objFSO.OpenTextFile(f.Path)`.